# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "mode", value = list(2L, 3L)) : replacement has 2 rows, data has 1

Tags: r

I have a data frame called New. using this data frame, I need to create a data frame using for loop and if-else condition

the New data frame is as follows

```
no    mode    start    end
1     S       0.026    33.059
2     T       33.176   38.057 
3     S       38.202   40.082
4     T       40.145   51.160
5     S       51.272   52.254
6     T       52.274   56.238
7     S       56.359   57.259
8     T       57.396   62.280
9     S       62.454   69.270
```

and the required data frame should be in the following form 
i.e. if mode "S" and its difference is <=1 (end-start),

```
no    mode    start    end
1     S       0.026    33.059
2     T       33.176   38.057 
3     S       38.202   40.082
4     T       40.145   62.280
5     S       62.454   69.270
```

for this, I am using the following code,

```
mode <- 0
start <- 0
end <- 0
abc <- data.frame(mode, start, end)
for (i in 1:nrow(New)) {
   if((New[i,2] = "S" && New[i,4]-New[i,3])>1) abc$mode[i] = New[i,2]
   else
 abc$mode[i] = New[i-1,2]
   if((New[i,2] = "S" && New[i,4]-New[i,3])>1) abc$start[i] = New[i,3]
   else
 abc$start[i] = New[i-1,3]
   if((New[i,2] = "S" && New[i,4]-New[i,3])>1) abc$end[i] = New[i,4]
   else
 abc$end[i] = New[i,4]
   }
```

i am getting the following error

```
Error in "S" && New[i, 4] - New[i, 3] : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `==` to test for equality.

Comment: now i am getting the error as follows    Error in New[i, 2] == "S" && New[i, 4] - New[i, 3] : 
  invalid 'y' type in 'x && y'

Comment: does `New[i,4]-New[i,3])>1` return TRUE/FALSE for all the `i`?

Comment: No, New[i,4]-New[i,3])>1 is not returning TRUE/FALSE. but the definition is correct

Comment: `if()` needs TRUE/FALSE

Comment: ALso see this: https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml#else to see how to constrict if/else correctly:

Comment: @snoram: I don't know if a styleguide is what he needs (although it doesn't hurt to get a start with good habits), but more some practice using `if`/`ifelse()` on simpler problems. Like running through the examples on `?ifelse` or a guide on using `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do away with the loop and the `if`s

```
New <- read.table(text="
no    mode    start    end
1     S       0.026    33.059
2     T       33.176   38.057 
3     S       38.202   40.082
4     T       40.145   51.160
5     S       51.272   52.254
6     T       52.274   56.238
7     S       56.359   57.259
8     T       57.396   62.280
9     S       62.454   69.270", 
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

abc <- New[New$mode == "S" & New$end - New$start <= 1, ]

abc
#   no mode start  end
# 5  5    S  51.3 52.3
# 7  7    S  56.4 57.3
```

Comment: actually, I want to combine the row having end-start <=1 to the above row. here the row having end-start <= 1 is considered as an error.....so i would like to combine start time and end time to the above row

Comment: @A.V.A.BharatKumar: Combine in what way?

Comment: from the data shown in the question, 4,5,6,7 and 8 rows are combined in the new data called 'abc'

Comment: @A.V.A.BharatKumar: You need to be more precise. Are you talking about something like `rbind()` or `merge()`, or an arithmetic combine. Something else?

Comment: @A.V.A.BharatKumar: `rbind()` with what? If you `rbind()` the matched rows with those in `New` you'll end up with duplicates.